# <button> tag is not taking in Html.fromHtml in android

Tags: android, html, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I want to display `html` data in text view all my `html` tags are working fine but only `<button>` tag is not taking this is my code `chielddesctext.setText(Html.fromHtml("<button>hi</button>"));`. Can some one can help me to solve this problem i tried but its not working.

Comment: @Selvin unnecessary commentary here; its not helpful, and may prevent the user from coming back, being involved in the community. I understand where you are coming from, and I've done it...we just all need to move past this.

Comment: I can't agree... Direct search with method's name + supported tag returns link to commonsware blog... Internet search is one of the most important programming skill. This comment should learn him to use search first, ask later...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Html.fromHtml()` does not honor all HTML tags. [This roster](https://commonsware.com/blog/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) is a bit old but is still fairly close to the current state of affairs.

Comment: Can you help me how to achieve <button> functionality in android

Comment: @GaneshP: Use an Android `Button` widget. Or, use a `WebView`. There is nothing a `TextView` can handle that would use an HTML `<button>` -- for example, there is no support for HTML forms either.